# How to select a dropdown menu item based on a value stored in a database with HTML and PHP?

Tags: php, html

Currently my dropdown looks as following:

```
$mon = array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun",
             "Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");

$output="<table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr class = 'tit'>
<td>Select Month
<select name='month' onChange='dateShow($infrasId,1)' id='month'>";
for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i ++) {
    $output.="<option value='$i'>".$mon[$i-1]."</option>";
} 
$output.="</select>";
```

I am getting the value of month through URL to a variable $month.

How can I select that month by default?

Comment: is that full code ? can you make your question more clearly

Comment: Did you not put a closing bracket (`}`) on the `if` on purpose?

Answer (score 3):

i didn't understand your question very well but i think this is what you are looking for

```
$output.="<option value='$i' " . ( mon[$i] == $_POST['month'] ? "selected" : "" ) . ">".$mon[$i-1]."</option>";
```

replace `$_POST['month']` with requested month name `variable`